# When did French 'é' become English 's'?

Tags: histoire

I've noticed that a there are quite a few French words that begin with 'é' or 'e' that have an equivalent in English that begins with 's'. Some examples are:

- écran : screen
- école : school
- estomac : stomach
- écureuil : squirrel
- étoile : star

I'm assuming that these words came from French into English so my question is did these words used to begin with an 's' in older forms of French, and if they did, when did this change occur? I'm guessing that they did because the Latin equivalents of many of them also have the 's'.

Merci pour toutes les réponses!

Comment: One thing that could have happened is that they had a common root in _es_, that went the _é_ way in French, and the _s_ way in English, rather than _é_ "becoming" _s_. The words in Latin should be a clue (for the words with a root in Latin).

Comment: A look at the etymology of those words (in wiktionary for instance) will show you that it's never been  an *e* turning into an *s*, but of an *e* being dropped along the way from an old Latin or Greek root. Some of the words you give (like school or star) did not come into English via French but via a Germanic language.  That's more a question for [Linguistics](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/) than for FL.

Comment: @Laure - I agree about Star but I think that School is probably Latin, no?

Comment: School cames from Greek to Latin but It was probably already present in the English vocabulary before William the Conqueror's time, thus Laure's comment.

Comment: @jlliagre - that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: It's possibly linked to a similar phenomenon :  the "s" turning into a " ^ ": Forrest>Forêt, Hospital>Hôpital, Arrest>Arrêt, Estre(Latin)>Être, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that Star is not from French/Latin but is has anglo-saxon roots (see German *Stern*.)

For most of the remaining words<sup>1</sup>, the reason is not that much *é* became *s* in English, but that Old French (and late Vulgar Latin in the western part of the Roman Empire) added a leading *i* → *e* in front of words starting with an *s* + consonant (*s impurum* = impure/imperfect "s"). This is called [Prothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prothesis_(linguistics)).

This phenomenon is more significant in Spanish where almost no word starts with *s* + consonant: e.g. FR *spécial* ←→ ES *especial*, *squelette* ←→ *esqueleto*, *stade* ←→ *estadio*, *style* ←→ *estilo*, *standard* ←→ *estándar*, *statue* ←→ *estatua*, *station* ←→ *estación*, …

Either this leading *e* was dropped when the French word was adopted by the English or maybe the word was already borrowed directly or indirectly from Latin so without the *e* in the first place as English like all Germanic languages has no problem with words starting with *st-*, *sk-*, *sp-*, and the likes.

In the meantime, many words starting with *es-* in French had their spelling changed to *é-* to match their pronunciation.

There is a counter-example of this evolution, French says *spécialement* when English can use *especially*.

<sup>1</sup> Excluding school which was probably already existing in the English vocabulary as the Latin *schola* spread early in northern European languages (Old German *scuola* (now *Schule*), Swedish *skola*, Gaelic *sgiol*, Welsh *ysgol*). Ref.[etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=school&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: Thanks - that's very helpful, it hadn't occurred to me to compare to Spanish, but that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Speaking about Spanish: *Spanish* / *espagnol*.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Yes and Italian uses *spagnolo* but it's not exactly the same case because Latin used *hispani/hispanorum* for "Spanish".

Comment: Bonne réponse :) Tout ce qui manque maintenant : a discussion of the perplexing changing nature of phonotactics that legitimates s+consonant onset clusters, then disallows them, then revives them...