# D'où provient le "é" dans le mot "école" ?

Tags: étymologie

Le mot "école" en Latin est "*schola*". Au fil du temps, il a dû y avoir un changement qui a préfixé la consonne.

Pourquoi croyez-vous que ce changement a eu lieu ? Serait-ce à cause d'un mot, à l'époque, qui apparaissait avant ?

Comment: La réponse se trouve ici : [When did French 'é' become English 's'?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25304/when-did-french-%c3%a9-become-english-s)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

À un certain moment dans l'évolution du latin vulgaire aux langues romanes occidentales (domaines gallo-roman et ibéro-roman), la combinaison de lettres s+consonne en début de mot est devenu "illégale" dans la phonologie (plus précisément la phonotactique) du roman. La solution qui s'est imposée à peu près universellement dans l'espace qui va du Rhéto-roman au portugais fut l'ajout d'un *e* épenthétique (techniquement, prothétique) devant ce *s*. Ce *e* subit par la suite les même transformations que les autres voyelles suivies d'un *s* ayant *a* par la suite disparu du français, résultant en *é* dans cette position. Ledit *s* demeure présent dans les équivalents des langues voisines:

- *École* vs. Es *escuela*, Pt *escola* (vs. It *scuola*, Ro *școală*)
- *Épée* vs. Es, Pt *espada*, Oc *espasa* (vs. It *spada*, Ro *spadă*)
- *Épaule* vs. Es *espalda*, Pt *espádua* (vs. It *spalla*)
- *État* vs. Es, Pt *estado*, OC *estat* (but It *stato*, Ro *stare*)

Le même phénomène d'épenthèse se rencontre en français québécois avec les mots commençant par re+consonne. La chute du *e* muet dans des mots comme *regarder* ou *revenir* résulte en une combinaison de lettres qui n'est pas naturelle en français. Le e-muet qui est ajouté devant le *r* subit ensuite fréquemment une modification phonologique commune en français québécois dont le résultat final est l'apparente transformation du préfixe *re-* en *ar-*.

Comment: Excellent. Also worth noting that depending on the time of borrowing, the *s* sometimes survived: *esprit*, *espérer*, *esthétique*, etc. Oh, and to make explicit the reason why prepending an *e* fixes this problem, which may not be clear to non-linguists: the *s* goes from sharing an onset cluster *sc* to being in a coda *s* followed by an onset *c*. An invisible difference but good evidence of phonological abstraction :)

Comment: Le premier stade de cette évolution a probablement été une voyelle instable /ɪ/ (à en juger par les inscriptions latine, qui lisent parfois "iscola" pour "scola") qui par la suite fusionné avec /e/, et qui n'apparaissait qu'en début de phrase ou quand le mot précédent se terminait par une consonne. C'est l'état qui persiste dans le Nord-Est de la zone d'Oïl, en picard ou en wallon: å scole (à l'école) - dén l'escole (dans l'école). Dans l'Est wallon, c'est l'inverse de la situation québécoise qui s'est produit: la voyelle est devenue épenthétique: li scole (l'école) - one sicole (une école)

Comment: @Eauquidort intéressant, n'étant guère plus qu'un amateur touche-à-tout, ce ne sont pas là des détails que je connaissait!